# Using Launch Screen Images with xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create a custom launch screen for ios devices.  I have created a story board called `Green Screen` and selected this as the launch screen file. I have added some images to the LaunchImage cassete in `Images.xcassetes`, though I have not filled every slot.  I have added an `Image View` box to the `Green Screen` view, but when when I select that image box and select the image dropdown, I do not see `LaunchImage` as a selection.

However, if I  create my own cassete, called `prototype launch image`, then when I go to to the image view, I can select ```prototype launch image``, add it to the image box, and stretch the image to fill the screen. However when the launch screen appears on building the app, the image is not centred and there is white space at bottom, so this does not seem to be a viable approach.

How do I add the `LaunchImage` cassette to this storyboard?

I am using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Make sure you have set appropriate constraints on the image view so that its size/position is set appropriately for the device it is being displayed on.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problems of the launch image have white spaces at the bottom and not being centred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) comment (see above), you need to choose the image view, and then set the constraints appropriately.